# smarthome test suite fails to execute

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to run the Google Smarthome automated tests on my service.  I test retrieves my service's devices and traits correctly.  However, when I start the test nothing happens.  No timeouts, no errors, nothing.

In my web browser developer's view I see the following error from Google's test suite app.  Could it be causing the test to fail to start?  Is this a problem on my end or Google's?

```
ERROR a.split is not a function
Yh  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18199
Zh.handleError  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18199
next    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18335
f   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18316
g.ht    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18293
g.next  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18292
g.ba    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18290
g.next  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18290
g.next  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18295
Ln.emit @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18315
(anonymous) @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18320
u.vb    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18086
p.run   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18078
Nn.Aa   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18319
Nj  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18320
u.handleError   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18086
p.Zo    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18079
t.gi    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18088
p   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18115
q   @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18115
load (async)        
ia  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18108
u.Xg    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18086
mi  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18169
u.Xg    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18086
mi  @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18083
u.Xg    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18086
p.Xg    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18080
p.Es    @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18081
(anonymous) @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18111
(anonymous) @   app_compiled.js?523e…-6feac3eecc6b:18977
Show 36 more frames
```

Comment: It may be an issue with the test suite not understanding your SYNC response. I would recommend filing an issue in the public tracker so the team can investigate the specifics: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/support

Answer (score 0):

To follow up here - the issue I had was I used the recommended definition for how to availableThermostatModes in the Sync request, which is a JSON area of strings.

Instead, I was asked to implement the deprecated representation format, which is a comma separated string.  Once switching to the deprecated format the suite ran.

See: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting

for the 2 formats.  Again, I had to use the deprecated format (Not the latest recommended format).